# Mapping Nested Lists to Nested Maps in Java 8

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

```
FamilyLegacy
   ParentList<Parent>

Parent //(Obj Class)
   ParentId // String ID
   ChildList<Child>  // List

Child
   ChildId
   GrandChildList<GrandChild>

GrandChild
    GrandChildId
   // Some GrandChild attribs    



{
  "parents": [
    {
      "Id": "P1",
      "parentName": "BigBob",
      "Child": [
        {
          "id": "C1",
          "name": "BOB",
          "grandChild": [
            {
              "grandChildId": "G1",
              "grandChildName": "John"
            },
            {
              "grandChildId": "G2",
              "grandChildName": "Doe"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "C2",
          "name": "Marley",
          "grandChild": [
            {
              "grandChildId": "G3",
              "grandChildName": "Katty"
            },
            {
              "grandChildId": "G4",
              "grandChildName": "Perry"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Outputs to ->

```
{
  "P1": {
    "name": "BigBob",
    "C1": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "G1": {
        "name": "John"
      },
      "G2": {
        "name": "Doe"
      }
    },
    "C2": {
      "name": "Marey",
      "G3": {
        "name": "Katty"
      },
      "G4": {
        "name": "Parry"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Consider the above nested object to list structure. Is there a way to convert this structure to a nested Map such as

```
 Map<String,Map<String, Map<String,Map<String,GrandChild>>>>
ParentId -> map of Parents ->map of childs ->map of grand childs  keyed with respective IDs
```

For instance First Level Mapping

```
  Map<String, Parent> parentMap =
    FamilyLegacy.getParents().stream().collect(
                   Collectors.toMap(Parent::getParentId,Function.identity()));
```

I am having a hard time visualizing the mapping and nesting, would appreciate if there is a way to do it using direct grouping or map other than iterating individual list objects

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: added a Json example to visualize the data structure.

Comment: Seriously, that data-structure is way too complex. Think about creating an utility class. A `NestedMap4<K1, K2, K3, K4, V>` maybe. Or, since this is about JSON, consider creating POJOs that match your structure and then read it in with GSON for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` to compose a nested map:

```
children.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        gc -> gc.getChild().getParent().getFamilyLegacy().getId(),
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            gc -> gc.getChild().getParent().getId(),
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                gc -> gc.getChild().getId()))));
```

You can see where does the nesting come from by lambdas for getting keys.

The type will be then `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, GrandChild>>>`. The first key fill be of `FamilyLegacy`, second of `Parent`, third from `Child`.

Edit:

Starting from `FamilyLegacy` you can use `Collectors.toMap`, like this:

```
familyLegacy.getParents().stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        p -> p.getId(),
        p -> p.getChildList().stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                c -> c.getId(),
                c -> c.getGrandChildList().stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                        gc -> gc.getId(),
                        Function.identity()))))));
```

Comment: THanks but looks like the flow is reverse there is no dependency of child in grand child and so on. Its the other way round. Let me put a JSON document that I am trying to visualize with some data.

Comment: thankyou.. that was exactly what i was looking for.